Automatically log in to a third-party web app that uses SSO
I have a web application (React + Node.js) that redirects users to a third-party web app, where they currently need to log in manually. I want to enable automatic login to this third-party web app so users don't have to log in themselves. I have access to the third-party's SSO configuration details, such as the ACS URL, SP-init SSO URL, etc.
I’m not very familiar with how SSO and SAML work, so I’m looking for guidance on how to achieve this. Most documentation I find focuses on setting up SSO for my own application, not on handling a third-party's SSO for automatic user login.
I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide. Thank you!

Given you mentioned "ACS URL", it sounds like this 3rd party app uses SAML.
If it supports IDP Initiated, that's the way to go.
So you would log in locally and then redirect using the IDP Initiated URL.
This sends an AuthnReponse to the 3rd party containing the user attributes, and the user is then automatically logged in.
